# ¿Cómo configurar el constructor de mpdf 7 en codeigniter 3.1?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, mpdf

He actualizado PHP a la versión 7 y codeigniter a la versión 3.1. Como usaba php 5.6 podía trabajar con mpdf v6 para imprimir en pdf, pero como actualicé php y codeigniter me salía error.

Mi preguntas son:
* ¿Cómo puedo configurar mpdf v7 en codeigniter 3.1 y php 7?
Actualice mi constructor y me sale los siguientes errores:
Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface' not found in /home/ighgroup/public_html/certificacion/application/libraries/third_party/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php on line 54

La carpeta que busca no existe en la librería que descargue desde el github
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91561/discussion-on-question-by-luis-medina-como-configurar-el-constructor-de-mpdf-7).

Answer (score 0):

**mPDF rabaja con PHP ≥ 5.6.0 and < 7.3.0.**

Tienes que instalar mPDF con composer: `composer require mpdf/mpdf`
La carpeta vendor, yo la tengo ubicada en `application/third_party`.

Luego creas la librería llamada `Pdf.php` en `application/libraries` con el siguiente contenido:
`

```
public function __construct(){

}

function pdf(){
    $CI = & get_instance();
    log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
}

function load($param=NULL){
    require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
    return new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'margin_left'       =>  '5',
        'margin_right'      =>  '5',
        'mode'              =>  'utf-8',     //Codepage Values OR Codepage Values
        'format'            =>  'A4',        //A4, Letter, Legal, Executive, Folio, Demy, Royal, etc
        'orientation'       =>  'P'          //"L" for Landscape orientation, "P" for Portrait orientation
    ]);
}
```

}`

**Y ya en tu controlador**:
Cargas la librería mPDF:
`$this->load->library('pdf');`

Renderizas el PDF con la función LOAD de la librería
`$pdf = $this->pdf->load();`Aquí puedes enviar los parámetros $param 
En lo sucesivo, las llamadas a los métodos de mPDF serán con
`$pdf->SetHeader($header);` por ejemplo.

Comment: mPDF TRABAJA con PHP ≥ 5.6.0 and < 7.3.0.